# Refer to DocumentRoot directive value

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Is there an option to refer **DocumentRoot** assigned value as a variable in the virtualhost declarations that come after?

For example:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/some/folder

    ModPagespeedLoadFromFileMatch "^http://([a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)/(.+)$" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/\\2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute ENVIRONMENT variables in apache2 configuration, for example

```
root@nada:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# grep DOCROOT 000-default 
    DocumentRoot ${DOCROOT}
root@nada:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# export DOCROOT="test"
root@nada:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# apachectl configtest
Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/apache2/test] does not exist
Syntax OK
root@nada:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled#
```

On Debian you have special file **/etc/apache2/envvars** where you can put those environment variables. On other distro it's probably done in different way.

Of course you can simply edit apache2 init.d script to load some environment varialbes :-)